# How do I search for two separate text strings in an Emacs buffer SIMULTANEOUSLY?

Tags: emacs

For example, I open a file called "abc.txt". Now I want to search for all occurrences of "he is" and "first" simultaneously. I want to be able to do a search forward i.e. Ctrl-s and I'll reach the next instance of *either* of the two search strings.

Answer (score 10):

```
M-x isearch-forward-regexp he is\|first
```

That command can also be found on <kbd>C-u C-s</kbd> and <kbd>C-M-s</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Just search for a regular expression, using e.g. `search-forward-regexp` with an appropriate regex search string:

`he is\|first`